# Find all pairs of identical columns in different tables in a database

Tags: sql, teradata

I would like to find identical column headers in different tables throughout a database (or across databases). I am trying to learn what are unique or foreign keys in each table fit with other keys in other tables in a multi-database SQL environment (using Teradata), and I think such a query would expedite this process.

I know how to query the database name, table name, and column name, but I don't know how to specify a condition to return only column headers in one table that exist in a different table

Here is some sample code that I think is the starter to this type of query:

```
select DatabaseName,TABLENAME as Tab1,Columnname as Col1, TABLENAME as Tab2, Columnname as Col2
from DBC.ColumnsV
order by DatabaseName,TABLENAME;
```

DatabaseName    Tab1    Col1    Tab2    Col2

Dat1            Table0  Col0    Table9  Col0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrews query simplified:

```
SELECT DatabaseName, TableName, ColumnName,
   Count(*) Over (PARTITION BY ColumnName) AS Cnt
FROM dbc.ColumnsV
QUALIFY Cnt > 1 -- only repeated columns
```

I think this is enough data to work with, but if you really want pairs of tables you need a self join:

```
WITH cte AS
 (
   SELECT DatabaseName, TableName, ColumnName,
      Count(*) Over (PARTITION BY ColumnName) AS Cnt
   FROM dbc.ColumnsV
   WHERE databasename = 'open_data'
   QUALIFY Cnt > 1 -- only repeated columns
 ) 
SELECT *
FROM cte AS t1
JOIN cte AS t2
  ON t1.ColumnName = t2.ColumnName       -- same column
WHERE t1.DatabaseName || '.' || t1.TableName < t2.DatabaseName || '.' || t2.TableName
```

Of course, this will greatly increase the number of rows, it returns each table name once, thus `n*(n-1)/2` rows for `n` tables with the same column name.

If you change the condition to `<>` instead of `<` you get *all* combinations and twice the number of rows, i,e, both `table1,table2` and `table2,table1`.

Comment: And this only works for a pair, what if the column name exists in 3 (or more) tables? Ugh.

Comment: @Andrew: I got 342 tables with a column named `DatabaseName` :-) I would prefer your approach.

Comment: I appreciate both your approaches to this!

Answer (score 0):

First we'll get a list of column names that are duplicated.  Then we join that back to ColumnsV and get whatever information you want on those columns.

```
with cols as (
select 
columnname ,
count (*) as cnt
from
dbc.columnsv
group by columnname
having count (*) > 1)

select
columnsv.*
from 
dbc.columnsv
inner join cols
    on columnsv.columnname = cols.columnname
```

Comment: Thank you, Andrew for the prompt response. This definitely seems close to what I am after. I take it that the databasename tablename and columname are the first instance of the columname? Is there any way to get that pair databasename tablename in this output?